# stop pnpm from creating symlink for a package

Tags: monorepo, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

we are in the process of migrating from yarn2.xx to pnpm (8.6.2) within our monorepo.

However one of our packages which is used in 3 different services. @prisma/client. generates a bunch of types associated with each service, plus binaries files. into /node_modules/.prisma (in yarn world).

However in pnpm no matter what we do, pnpm puts the `.prisma` folder into the root node_modules, which breaks the types for other services (since each service .prisma must be different).

we have attempted several variations of config changes in .npmrc as per [docs](https://pnpm.io/npmrc#dependency-hoisting-settings), but we always end up with prisma/client being a symlink to the version in the root.

```
public-hoist-pattern[]=*
public-hoist-pattern[]=!*prisma/client*
```

or

```
public-hoist-pattern[]=*
public-hoist-pattern[]=!*prisma*
```

or

```
hoist-pattern[]=!*prisma*
```

etc.

All these variations result in pnpm creating always a symlink within each service to the root, and generated types to end up there.

Is there a way to stop pnpm from creating symlinks for specific packages, similar to what nohoist in yarn workspaces does?

Comment: no, couldnt find anything just threads of people with a similar issue.

Comment: Running into the same issue. It's surprising how there's so many people using prisma and pnpm, but no one has voiced this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this issue by explicitly configuring Prisma to generate the client binaries to a custom output directory `node_modules/prisma-client`:

```
// prisma/schema.prisma
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["postgresqlExtensions"]
  output          = "../node_modules/prisma-client"
}
```

Then doing a search-and-replace of the import statements, replacing `from '@prisma/client'` with `from 'prisma-client'`.